# AJAX возвращает JSON с HTML тегами

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

На сервере есть search.php, который получает поисковый запрос в виде строки и ищет совпадения в .json файлах в отдельной директории и возвращает массив объектов в виде:

```
[search_result_0, search_result_1, search_result_2, ...]
```

Но если я пытаюсь отправить на сервер запрос "как " (с пробелом на конце), то сервер возвращает мой json и + html теги непонятного происхождения:

```
[search_result_0, search_result_1, search_result_2, ...]
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="position:relative; top:0; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto; z-index:99999">

    </div>
</div>
```

В самом search.php только одна команда echo. Для подробности вопроса оставлю тело search.php и тело одного из json файлов в котором происходит поиск:

**search.php**

```
<?php
if (
    isset($_GET["search_request"]) && 
    !empty($_GET["search_request"])
) {
    $search_results = [];

    $subjects = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/subjects"); //there are .json files in the folder in which i search the questions.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($subjects); $i++) {
        $file_name = $subjects[$i];
        if (preg_match("/.json$/", $file_name)) { //continue if it is .json file
            $subject_data = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/subjects/" . $file_name);
            $subject_data_decoded = json_decode($subject_data);

            for ($a = 0; $a < count($subject_data_decoded); $a++) {
                $question = $subject_data_decoded[$a];
                if (mb_stripos($question[0], $_GET["search_request"]) !== false) {
                    array_push($search_results, [
                        $question[0], //the question
                        $question[1][0] //the first possible answer
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($search_results);
}
```

**subject.json**

```
[
    ["question 1",[
        "answer 1",
        "answer 2",
        "answer 3",
        "answer 4",
        "answer 5"
    ]],
    ["question 2",[
        "answer 1",
        "answer 2",
        "answer 3",
        "answer 4",
        "answer 5"
    ]],
    //...and so on
]
```

В чем может быть проблема? И почему какие-то конкретные запросы типа "как " заставляют сервер вести себя подобным образом?

Comment: 1. search.php точно вызывается напрямую? нигде не подключается?
2. ответ от самого search.php уже такой приходит? или после обработки яваскриптом? Пробовали вызывать search.php напрямую  типа search.php?search_request=как%20

Comment: @SergeyShitikov да, напрямую. Примерно так выглядит запрос:

$.ajax({
 url:'/php/search.php',
 type:'GET',
 data: {
  search_request: request
 },
 dataType:'json'
})

Comment: @SergeyShitikov ответ приходит с тегами во вкладку Network в консоле. Т.е. это ответ самого search.php получается

Comment: попробуйте в search.php указать тип данных через заголовок: header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

Comment: Также попробуйте отключить вывод любых ошибок и посмотреть, будут ли по прежнему приходить теги:
    error_reporting(0);
    @ini_set('display_errors', 0);

Comment: @SergeyShitikov сейчас попробовал вызвать напрямую через search.php?search_request=как%20. Результат тот-же. На странице отображается json массив и теги под ним. Добавление заголовка тоже не помогло. Отключение вывода ошибок тоже. Отключение вывода ошибок из htaccess тоже не помогло.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74372/discussion-between-sergey-shitikov-and-misha-saidov).

Answer (score 1):

Так как текст php файла приведен не полностью (например нет закрывающего php тега), остается предположить, что в конце файла Вы просто не удалили закрывающий тег html. Он и передается вместе с остальной информацией.

Comment: Там в самом сервере была ошибка (возможно потому что бесплатный был какой-то). На платном тот же код заработал без проблем.